# Delphi Event Bus DEB 32-bit compile error

Tags: delphi

Using DEB on D11.0, I get an undeclared-identifier error in `EventBus.Helpers` line 342 when compiling for a 32-bit target *only*.  The same code compiles and runs fine for a 64-bit target (and for both targets in D10.2.3.)  The referenced property `TRttiType.IsInterface` does not exist in `System.Rtti`.  Did EMB do something screwy here?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you by any chance remove DUnitX.Utils from the uses because that one introduces some helpers that have that method. Also in the latest version from GitHub line 342 in that unit is an empty line so you might want to update these sources.

Comment: I didn't remove any units.  I'm off on another project now but will update my sources and recheck things Monday.  Thanks, Stefan.

Comment: Turns out that, in the version of the source I have, the uses clause for `DUnitX.Utils` in `EventBus.Helpers` is `{$IFDEF Win64}` 'ed out - which explains why it builds for 64-bit targets but not 32-bit.  There's no 32-bit DCU for DUnitX.Utils on my system, so I've got to update both DUnitX and DEB.